# Copying cells using a loop

Tags: excel, while-loop, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to copy data from sheet 1 (which is manually updated by users) to sheet 2 (which acts as a database). I need to write a loop code, which would copy complete list of processes, and then add user name next to it. E.g.

- Process a   User 1
- Process b   User 1
- Process a   User 2
- Process b   User 2
- Process a   User 3
- Process b   User 3

Processes are listed in one column on sheet 1, users are listed in one row, and their number/names will change. The loop needs to stop copying when there is a blank cell after the last user.

I am new to VBA and can't get my head around what I am missing!

```
Sheets(1).Activate
'Range(6, cln).Select
Range("J6").Select
 Do Until IsEmpty(Selection.Value)

                     'copy proceses
                     Range("C8").Select
                     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
                     Sheets(2).Activate
                     Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     Application.CutCopyMode = False

                     'Copy users
                     Sheets(1).Activate
                     ActiveCell.Copy
                     Sheets(2).Activate
                     Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     Application.CutCopyMode = False



        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, assuming your processes are in column A and your users are in row 1:

```
dim resultProcess as variant
dim resultUsers as variant

set rngProcesses = sheets(1).Range("A2:A200")
set rngUsers = sheets(1).range("B1:ZZ1")
set rngTarget = sheets(2).range("A1:A200")

resultProcess = array()
resultUsers = array()

i=0
For Each rng in rngProcesses
    process = rng.value
    resultProcess[i] = process
    i = i + 1
next
j=0
For Each item in rngUsers
    user = rng.value
    resultUsers[i] = user
    j = j + 1
Next

i=0
j=0

for each cell in rngTarget
    cell.value = resultProcess[i] + resultUsers[j]
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
next
```

Comment: Not really, I'm not sure where the copy/paste code is supposed to go. How does it know to stop when it reaches blank cell in Users row? You may have to explain the code a little more!

Comment: @Ivan You would put this code inside the code for Sheet1. In the VBA editor, just double click where it says "Sheet1" and start entering in the code. As for the code, you manually define where all of your data is, so you adjust the rngProcesses and rngUsers and rngTarget to reflect the range your data is found on, and where you want your code to go. It then loops through the ranges you defined and adds the values to two arrays. The last loop will loop simultaneously through both arrays and concatenate them and enter them in cell by cell to your rngTarget location.

Comment: I put your code in VBA, on its own. I set ranges as Set rngProcesses = Sheets(1).Range("A2:A200")
Set rngUsers = Sheets(1).Range("J6:AJ6")
Set rngTarget = Sheets(2).Range("B2:C200"). When trying to run it, the first error I get is at ResultProcess [i] line - compile error, expected sub, function or property. Also cell.value line is highlighted in red, I presume that will break too

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried my code before posting that answer. The idea is that you add each of the values in the rngProcesses range to an array, then add each of the values in the rngUsers range, then populate the first cell in the rngTarget range with the concatenation of the first item in the resultProcess array and the first item in the resultUsers array. The process repeats for every cell in the rngTarget range.